# Multiple Clean Url Variables

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering how to pass several (two) values through url as a clean url.
I've done clean urls before, but never with multiple values and it doesn't seem to be working.

This is what the url looks like now:

```
http://example.com/?user=Username&page=1
```

This is what I want it to look like

```
http://example.com/user/Username/page/1
```

I've tried other answers that I've seen on here, but they aren't working for this certain deal.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't match real existing files so CSS, scripts, images aren't rewritten
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Match the first two groups before / and send them to the query string
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?user=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Thanks. :)
I'm using PHP by the way. :)

Also, will I still be able to use $_GET with this? I thought so, but I also somewhere else where it said you can't... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing several matches, try:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't match real existing files so CSS, scripts, images aren't rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [L]
```

This will take a URL like:

```
http://example.com/a/b/c/d
```

to the URI:

```
/index.php?a=b&c=d
```

> will I still be able to use $_GET with this? I thought so, but I also somewhere else where it said you can't.

In the above example, when you look at `$_GET['a']` you'd get `b`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to test this out, but unfortunately, I'm using 000webhost as a free host and for some reason its htaccess is messing up :/